# Intellij does not show warnings

Tags: compiler-warnings, intellij-14

I am using IntelliJ 14.0.3 Community Edition.  What I would like is for IntelliJ to show me warning in the Messages Windows and/or the Problems Scope.  Warnings show up as yellow lines in the Editor window and in Analysis; however, this is not very useful if you are trying to track down warning in other files without first opening each of them.

I have looked for some setting or switch within IntelliJ, but I have not found anything.  It really would be nice that when you compile/make/build, all warning showed up in Messages Window and/or Problems Scope just like errors do.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: One more thing.  Another person here is using Eclipse (the latest version) and can see both errors and warnings in Eclipse's Problems Window...